# How to get if dynamic checkbox is checked without using javascript?

Tags: asp.net

So, I have a `checkbox1` added dynamically in a `modal bootstrap` and this has an `CheckedChanged` event that add some checkbox's `("checkbox1.1" "checkbox1.2" "checkbox1.3")`,dynamically as well, so my question is, when I `postback` (on a submit or link button) how can I know if my `checkbox1.1` is checked or not? I can actually know if my `checkbox1` is checked or not because i recreate the controls on every `postback` but the `checkbox1.1` i cant because its always depending if my `checkbox1` is checked or not. Is there a way i can get it without recreating the `checkbox1.1` in my `postback` ? (without using `javascript` if possible).

I already tried , Lists, Disctionary, Sessions, Viewstates it seams like if i dont recreat the controls (checkbox1.1) i cant save them and they will be lost

```
foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
{
    i++;
    CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
    chk.Attributes["class"] = "mycheckbox";
    chk.Font.Name = "Tahoma";
    chk.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
    chk.Text = item[descricao].ToString();

    //If true add checkbox id = checkbox1
    if (divsname.ID == "DadosIdentificacao")
    {
        chk.ID = checkbox + i;
        chk.AutoPostBack = true;
        chk.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.chkEventos);                        
    }
    //Else checkboxid = checkbox1.1
    else
    {
        chk.ID = checkbox + item[descricao].ToString() + i;
    }

    divsname.Controls.Add(chk);
    ListData.Add(chk);
}
```

I can get if `checkbox1` is checked or not but my `checkbox1.1` control disappear on `postback`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by instead of creating my *checkbox* dynamically, fill a *Session["list"]* with all my *checkbox* and then creat a new list *List List1 = Session["list"] as List* and  work with that same List1 by hiding or showing my checkbox.